# WKWebView doesn't follow redirects

Tags: wkwebview

If I load a URL in a browser, it redirects (there is a 302 code in Charles). When a `WKWebView` loads the same URL, it doesn't - it's just a 200.

Is there a way to get WKWebView to follow HTTP redirections? Do I need to override some method in maybe the navigation delegate?